# C# SQL Server database reverse engineering

Tags: c#, sql-server, reverse-engineering

I made a C# program with a login interface and used a SQL Server database. Can someone recover my database information by decompiling the EXE program generated?

Comment: salam yacine, what do you mean by "recover my database" ?

Comment: I want to know if someone can find my database informations , username,password,db after decompiling my EXE file

Comment: then you can use reflector to decompile you .exe and see the source code (https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/)

Comment: using System.Data.SqlClient;

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString =
"Data Source=localhost" +
"Initial Catalog=luncher;" +
"User id=azerty;" +
"Password=azerty;";
conn.Open();

my c# code contains this SQL server string connection, I want to know if someone can get this lines after decompiling my program

Comment: This is something you can easily research.  There are hundreds of posts on the issue here already as well as a number of great articles on MSDN

Comment: Yes.. Someone can use decompiler or reflector and figure out the details of the connection string from your code. Do you want it to be protected so that no one can identify the username and password ?

Comment: It's common knowledge in the software development field that you (the company) don't embed your (the company's) database credentials in the client application. You would want to authenticate with an API that could limit that access. Of course if the client application expected the user to plug in their own on premises or remote database that would be a different story.

Comment: If I got your question,it's possible to get application connection string especially if you save it in config file,if you embed it in your code someone would just need refactor to get it and your code also which mean even if you encrypt it one can reverse engineering and recreate it.depending on your requirement you might consider consider not adding it to config file,u might also consider add it in you code then using app like Confuserex which could reduce chances of common coder from opening you code.

Answer (score 1):

Note: I interpret your question as someone who had the username and password for a database and has since lost it and is looking for a way to get it back. If your question was asked in the sense of "is it possible for a person to hack my program and read my connection string" then using the word "anyone" instead of "someone" would have made this more clear

Onto the answer:

Yes, "Someone" can, as long as that someone is you - we aren't here to do that for you

In an ideal world, no reverse engineering would be needed - just open the config file and read the connection string out of it. did you save your connection string in the config file?

If you hard coded it, use something like ILSpy to decompile your .net exe. Use of ilspy or similar decompilers  is not difficult; most of them can work by you dropping the exe into the main window of the decompiler and then reading the code

Once you have the connection string you'll probably have the username and password if you didn't go to any extended means to hide them